# Facing "'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'median'" error while using median

Tags: python, numpy

I was going through a cheat sheet of NumPy and found the `median()` function. As I was trying it, an error was thrown. [Here](https://datacamp-community-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/da466534-51fe-4c6d-b0cb-154f4782eb54), you can find the cheat sheet. The code is:

```py
import numpy as np
check = np.array([1, 2, 3])
check.median()
```

The error message is:

> 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'median'

In the [official NumPy doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.median.html), I found that I should use `median()` as `np.median(check)`. So, I was wondering if `check.median()` is an obsolete method or I was doing anything in a wrong way?

The NumPy version I was using was 1.19.5. Then I upgraded it to the latest version (1.21.2). Still, the same error persists.

Comment: `np.median(check)`.

Comment: @Ch3steR So, is `check.median()` wrong?

Comment: @Imran `np.ndarray.median` does not exist, `np.median` does.

Comment: @Imran Yes, `np.median` is a standalone function. When you write `check.median`, since `check` is `np.ndarray`, python tries to call `np.ndarray.median` and `np.ndarray` has no method `median` defined.

Comment: Thanks both of you (can't mention two of you). The creator of the cheat sheet should be alerted about this.

Comment: The question has been closed. The reason stated is that it was "caused by a typo or a problem that can no longer be reproduced"! The question might be closed for any other reasons but I can't understand how this question is a typo or not reproducible. So, I don't know what to edit to reopen it.

Comment: I have understood the reason for closing (after posting about it in meta). The typo that was stated as the reason for closing in fact was made by DataCamp in the cheat sheet. I have reported the typo to DataCamp. After their action, I will remove this question.